# How to change place of the next bits?(use only bit operations)

Tags: c

for example 10'00'11'01'01  -> 01'00'11'10'10

```
void main() {
  unsigned int num = 78;
  unsigned int num2 = change_bit(num);
  printf("%d\n", num2); //141
}
```

I need a function like that.

Comment: are you using c or c++ ?

Comment: I'm using C.But I know that bit operation is the same as in C as in C++.

Comment: You can do it using an XOR temporary. But, depending on your requirements, and assembler solution might be the way to go here. See http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#SwappingBitsXOR.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are bitwise shift (bit-shift) operators and how do they work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/what-are-bitwise-shift-bit-shift-operators-and-how-do-they-work)

Comment: Use the >> bitwise operator. See here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bitwise_operators.htm

Comment: It is not really clear by your example what the function is supposed to do. Also you should make more clear wether you are using C or C++, they may look the same at first glance, but they are fundamentaly different!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, it seems that you need a function that swaps position of every 2 bits in a number. few examples:

1. 10'00'11'01'01 -> 01'00'11'10'10
2. 11'01'10'10'11 -> 11'10'01'01'11

for this operation, a very simple function is following:

```
unsigned int change_bit(unsigned int num)
{
    return ((num & 0xAAAAAAAA) >> 1) | ((num & 0x55555555) << 1);
}
```